# C2100:illegal indirection

Tags: c++, stl, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve the following dynamic programming problem:Given an infinite amount of quarters(25),dimes(10),nickels(5) and pennies(1),write code to calculate the number of ways to represent n cents.

This is my code:

```
int coins(int n,unordered_map<int,int>& memo){
    if (n < 0){
        return 0;
    }
    else if (n == 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else if (n == 5){
        return 2;
    }

    unordered_map<int, int>::iterator iter = memo.find(n);
    int coinsValue;
    if (iter == memo.end()){
        coinsValue = coins(n - 1,memo) + coins(n - 5,memo) + coins(n - 10,memo) + coins(n - 25,memo);
        memo.insert(n, coinsValue);
    }

    return iter->second;
}

int coins(int n){
    unordered_map<int, int> memo;
    return coins(n, memo);

}


int main(){
    cout << coins(10) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

`error C2100:illegal indirection`

but I cant find what is causing the problem,  the code looks clean.

Comment: Could you show us the entire error message, not just ""illegal indirection""?

Comment: Additionally, you must extract a [mcve]. Without it, your question is considered off-topic.

Comment: `memo.insert(n, coinsValue);` should be `memo.emplace(n, coinsValue);` [`std::unordered_map::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert) expects a single `value_type` which is a `std::pair<const Key, T>`.

Comment: And `iter` remains `end()` after the `if`, leading to an invalid dereference.

Comment: What is the code attempting to solve?

Comment: The whole error is C2100:illegal indirection @hlt

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the insertion wrong. It should be:

```
memo.insert(pair<int,int>(n, coinsValue));
```

Or even simpler just use:

```
memo[n] = coinsValue;
```

Make sure to return `memo[n]` in the following line or you will get `Segmentation fault.`